# Infinite scrolling UITableView with numbers

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch

I need to create infinite table with numbers, that is, when scrolling, new cells with numbers should be created.

I create `APICaller` with counter, pagination, arrays and while loop.
Also I create `UITableView` with `func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView)` which append new values in a table.

**My `ViewController` with `UITableView`**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UIScrollViewDelegate {
    
    private let apiCaller = APICaller()
    
    private let tableView: UITableView  = {
        let tableView = UITableView(frame: .zero, style: .grouped)
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self,
                           forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
        return tableView
    }()
    
    private var data = [Int]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.addSubview(tableView)
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.frame  = view.bounds
        apiCaller.fetchData(pagination: false, completion: { [weak self] result in
            switch result {
            case.success(let data):
                self?.data.append(contentsOf: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self?.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            case.failure(_):
                break
            }
        })
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text =  String(describing: data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        let position = scrollView.contentOffset.y
        if position > (tableView.contentSize.height-100-scrollView.frame.size.height) {
            guard !apiCaller.isPaginating else { return }
            apiCaller.fetchData(pagination: true) { [weak self] result in
                switch result {
                case .success(let moreData):
                    self?.data.append(contentsOf: moreData)
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self?.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                case .failure(_):
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case of `APICaller` I have only 100 cells, which corresponds to the loop constraint (but if i remove break from the while loop, nothing appears)

```
class APICaller {
    
    private var counter = 0
    
    var isPaginating = false
    
    func fetchData(pagination: Bool = false, completion: @escaping (Result<[Int], Error>) -> Void) {
        if pagination {
            isPaginating = true
        }
        DispatchQueue.global().asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (pagination ? 3 : 2), execute: {
            var newData: [Int] = [0]
            var originalData: [Int] = [0]
            
            while true {
                self.counter += 1
                originalData.append(self.counter)

                if  self.counter == 100 {
                    break
                }
            }
            
            completion(.success(pagination ? newData : originalData))
            if pagination {
                self.isPaginating = false
            }
        })
    }
}
```

So, how can i get a table with infinite numbers?

Answer (score 1):

The basic idea is right. When you scroll to a point where more rows are needed, fetch them. But doing this in the `UIScrollViewDelegate` is an expensive place to do that. I.e., that method is called for every pixel of movement and will result in many redundant calls.

Personally, I would advise moving this logic to the appropriate table view methods. For example, at a bare minimum, you might do it in the `UITableViewDataSource` method (i.e., if you are handling a row more than *n* rows from the end of your data set, fetch more data). E.g.,

```swift
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return data.count + 1                     // NB: one extra for the final “busy” cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if (indexPath.row + 50) >= data.count {   // scrolled within 50 rows of end
            fetch()
        }

        if indexPath.row >= data.count {          // if at last row, show spinner
            return tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "busy", for: indexPath)
        }

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = String(describing: data[indexPath.row])
        return cell
    }
}
```

A few things to note there:

- I'm reporting one more row than I have thus far. This is for my “busy” cell (a cell with a spinning `UIActivityIndicatorView`). That way, if the user ever scrolls faster than the network response can handle, we at least show the user a spinner to let them know that we are fetching more data.
- Thus, the `cellForRowAt` checks the `row`, and shows the “busy cell” if necessary.
- And in this case, when I'm within 50 items of the end, I will initiate a fetch of the next batch of data.

Even better than the above, I would also marry the `UITableViewDataSource` implementation with a `UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching`. Thus, set the `tableView.prefetchDataSource` and then implement `prefetchRowsAt`:

```swift
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSourcePrefetching {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, prefetchRowsAt indexPaths: [IndexPath]) {
        guard
            let maxIndexPath = indexPaths.max(by: { $0.row < $1.row }),  // get the last row, and
            maxIndexPath.row >= data.count                               // see if it exceeds what we have already fetched
        else { return }

        fetch(pagination: true)
    }
}
```

---

By the way, a few notes on `fetch`:

```swift
func fetch(pagination: Bool = false) {
    apiCaller.fetchData(pagination: pagination) { [weak self] result in
        guard
            let self = self,
            case .success(let values) = result
        else { return }

        let oldCount = self.data.count
        self.data.append(contentsOf: values)
        let indexPaths = (oldCount ..< self.data.count).map { IndexPath(row: $0, section: 0) }
        self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Note, I would advise *not* “reloading” the whole table view, but rather just “inserting” the appropriate rows. I've also moved the “am I busy” logic into the `APICaller`, where it belongs:

```swift
class APICaller {
    private var counter = 0
    private var isInProgress = false

    func fetchData(pagination: Bool = false, completion: @escaping (Result<[Int], Error>) -> Void) {
        guard !isInProgress else {
            completion(.failure(APIError.busy))
            return
        }

        isInProgress = true

        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + (pagination ? 3 : 2)) { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }

            let oldCounter = self.counter
            self.counter += 100
            self.isInProgress = false

            let values = Array(oldCounter ..< self.counter)
            completion(.success(values))
        }
    }
}

extension APICaller {
    enum APIError: Error {
        case busy
    }
}
```

I not only simplified the `APICaller`, but also made it thread-safe (by moving all state mutation and callbacks on the the main queue). If you start some asynchronous task on a background queue, dispatch the updates and callback to the main queue. But do not mutate objects from background threads (or if you must, add some synchronization logic).